# C# Windows Forms App 'Parameter is not valid.'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, windows-forms-designer, c#-2.0

in this example I'm trying to pass parameter from `Main.cs`

```
string head = "Error", msg = "Please chek username and password";

public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void bunifuThinButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Message message = new Message(head, msg);
    message.ShowDialog();
}
```

to `Message.cs`

```
public Message()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public Message(string a, string b)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    bunifuCustomLabel1.Text = a;
    bunifuCustomLabel2.Text = b;
}
```

but i try with many different examples every time get this error

**System.ArgumentException:** 'Parameter is not valid.'

on this line

```
message.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: can't understand you

Comment: On your example Message.cs doesn't contain a method called ShowDialog()

Comment: @Greg,  "Message" class is derived from Form class . so ShowDialog() from "System.Windows.Forms" class

Answer (score 0):

Please rename the second Form from "Message" to something else such as "Form2". There is a build in struct Message in System.Windows.Forms.dll.
I've tried to make an example. i hope it helps:

```
     public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string head = "Error", msg = "Please chek username and password";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 message = new Form2(head, msg);
            message.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Form2(string a, string b)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = a;
        label2.Text = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: this line is deleted i forget it when i write my code here

Answer (score 0):

It Works for me, i think your code missing something apart from the code which you shared. Ok I'm sharing the working example.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Main : Form
{
    string head = "Error", msg = "Please chek username and password";
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Message message = new Message(head, msg);
        message.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
 }
}
```

Message Form

```
public partial class Message : Form
{
    public Message()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Message(string a, string b)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = a;
        label2.Text = b;
    }

    private void Message_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Screen Shot

[image]